# Can I ask this question?

Tags: discussion

Having come across [this post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/3211/which-city-to-visit-in-europe-during-january), I wondering what cities/areas in Europe should be avoided in November/December.

For instance, I had originally planned to visit Scotland, but reading the official Scotland tourism website, they themselves even stated Scotland was not ideal to visit during winter, unless one intended on skiing.

I don't mean that one should avoid a city or area simply because it is cold. For instance, German Christmas markets are in themselves worth seeing and London is still visitable in the rain so long as one brings water-proof clothing.

There may be many reasons not to visit an area; one such factor could be terrible weather. As an extreme example, in the U.S., we have regions that have hurricane and tornado seasons -- not at all an ideal time to visit those locaitons. Thus, if an area simply has unbearable or even dangerous conditions during a certain time of the year, it would be worth noting. Referring back to the Scotland example, the vast majority of people visit Scotland (particularly the Scotland Highlands) to see nature and green, rolling hills -- I believe this is why their own website suggests not coming. On the other hand, Nov/Dec would be perfect for those who want to ski in Switzerland (or even hike if you enjoy hiking colder conditions), so snow and cold conditions wouldn't be a limiting factor. In other words, if it's a well known fact that people visit a certain area for a certain activity, but during Nov/Dec, weather or otherwise make it a not-so-ideal place to visit, then please do make note of it. Other examples may be that during Nov/Dec, some areas or closed or take time to remodel/reconstruct because it is the slow season.

Essentially, I'd like to know if there are areas would only provide a limited experience or areas that may be worth visiting at another time.

(And, of course, I don't expect any one post, or even the sum of all posts, to be an exhaustive list.)

---

I deleted the post as a more experienced user had stated it was too broad. I was hoping that even after finding a *similar* post, which was highly upvoted, was still able to receive answers. Even that post could have had many possibilities. Additionally, I even state that I *do not* expect an exhaustive list.

Comment: The question you pointed out is something I'd consider a legacy question, when the community was still forming itself. It would likely be closed voted if asked now, as we've discovered through the community what works for our Q&A format and what doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

For many kinds of trip, Scotland is very nice to visit in the winter! Not all kinds of visit, sure, but that's why you need to ask *specific* questions, as explained in [answer to your previous query](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1439/26)

If you want someone to do all the thinking for you, pay an expensive travel agent or a concierge. If you're happy to put the time in to wade through lots of discussions to find the few specific bits for you, ask on a forum. If you'd like us to help you (which we're more than willing to do!), you need to put some time in up-front to frame your query as a number of [practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help). We can then answer those, you'll get the individual pieces to pull together to build your ideal trip, and future visitors to the site will be able to learn from it too.

It sounds like Scotland is the first place you're interested in, so I'd suggest you begin by asking one or two questions about how the weather + daylight will affect the things you plan to do at different times of the year, then go on from there. If you need help with phrasing a question, then [jump on the Travel SE chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/591) and people there should be able to help you work out how best to ask it.